# Variables in braces - PHP coding question

Tags: php, mysql, variables, syntax, echo

This is my PHP/MySQL script:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'test') or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('info1') or die (mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from automobiles");

    //Table starting tag and header cells
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //Display the results in different cells
        echo "<dd><dl><img src=' " . $row['image'] . " '>" . $row['manufacturer'] ." " . $row['model'] . "</dd></dl>";
        echo "<dd><dl>" . $row['carinfo'] . "</dd></dl>";
    }

    //Table closing tag
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

However, would it work if I did it this way:

```
{$myvariable}
```

Is it a good idea to code the variables with the braces, or as:

```
echo " . $row['variable']. "
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
echo "<dd><dl>{$row['carinfo']}</dd></dl>";
```

You cannot do this:

```
echo "<dd><dl>$row['carinfo']</dd></dl>";
```

---

This also wont work:

```
echo '<dd><dl>{$row['carinfo']}</dd></dl>';
```

Your output would **actually** be:

> `<dd><dl>{$row[` SOME PHP ERROR

This is due to using single quotes instead of double quotes. And the error would be because you did not escape the single quotes inside the variable.

If you did this:

```
echo '<dd><dl>{$row["carinfo"]}</dd></dl>';
```

Your output would **actually** be:

> `<dd><dl>{$row["carinfo"]}</dd></dl>`

For the same single quote vs double quote reasoning.

Comment: +1 was going to say the same thing that I saw 2 new answers :P

Comment: To add a bit information: please keep in mind that "inlining" variables works only if your string delimiters are double-quotes (i.e. `"`). Strings wrapped with single quotes (`'`) won't get processed (i.e. no variables or escape characters will be replaced)

Comment: @Martin -- that aspect has been added.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer using the `" " . $row['variable']. " "` syntax because it's easier to read code, specially if you have a code syntax highlighter. But using this syntax is acceptable: `"{$var['field']}"`.